# access storage map from another pallet without trait pallet Config

Tags: pallet, storage, frame, storagenmap, liberland

I have one pallet with a storagemap that I want to use/call with another Pallet.

After doing some research I ran over Centrifuge fudge project(https://github.com/centrifuge/fudge/blob/376e4d6b89324b24d131e7f7c19c7c504871d5d3/core/src/builder/relay_chain.rs#L62-L70) that has a similar approach.

I tried to do this using a StorageInstance:

```rust
pub mod llmmod {
    use super::*;
    use frame_support::{
        storage::types::{StorageMap, StorageValue, ValueQuery},
        traits::StorageInstance,
        Blake2_128Concat, Twox64Concat,
    };
    // ParaLifecyclesPrefix, based on centrifuge
    pub struct LLMPoliticsCopy;

    impl StorageInstance for LLMPoliticsCopy {
        fn pallet_prefix() -> &'static str {
            "llm"
        }

        const STORAGE_PREFIX: &'static str = "LLMPolitics";
    }
    pub type LLMPolitics<T> = frame_support::storage::types::StorageMap<
        LLMPoliticsCopy,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        u128,
        frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery,
    >;

    pub fn check_pooled_llm<T: frame_system::Config>(sender: T::AccountId) -> bool {
        LLMPolitics::<T>::contains_key::<T::AccountId>(sender)
    }

}


Then I check the storage map with a regular contains, to check if the account is in the storage map:

ensure!(!llmmod::check_pooled_llm::<T>(who.clone()), Error::<T>::NoPolLLM);
```

The code is compiling, but the storage map is not syncing, when I insert a new entry using the pallet, it does not sync.

Is there a way to Query a storage map in another pallet without adding new_pallet::Config to the config trait ? Is there a way to get around this?

I need the democracy pallet to query a storage map from another pallet but adding `+ LLM_Pallet::Config` in the trait config for the pallet just introduce a lot of bugs.

Is there a way to query storage maps that other pallets have without the pallet's config? manually adding a trait for it?

from pallet:

```rust
    #[pallet::storage] // allocated in politics
    #[pallet::getter(fn get_politics_balance)]
    pub(super) type LLMPolitics<T: Config> =
        StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, T::Balance, ValueQuery>;
```

Link to the code repo:
https://github.com/liberland/liberland_substrate/tree/storage
https://github.com/liberland/liberland_substrate/blob/storage/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs
https://github.com/liberland/liberland_substrate/blob/storage/frame/llm/src/lib.rs

Comment: seems like other people can access storage maps locally with some StorageInstance magic

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to provide some overview, of what I think are the three possible solutions (if one does NOT want to tight couple - i.e. `trait Config: other_pallet::Config` the pallets).

1. Create keys manually
2. Create `StorageMap` manually
3. Abstraction via trait

Generally, I would suggest always favoring tight coupling or soft coupling (solution 3.) over creating keys or maps manually.
The manual solutions are error-prone and can lead to pallets accessing different storage locations and/or assuming different types in the storage, which in the end can lead to nasty bugs.

## Setup

- pallet_provider

  - Provides:

    ```rust
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub type DataStorage<T: Config> =
       StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Index, T::Data>;
    ```
  - Stores `T::Data` under the key `T::Index`
- pallet_consumer

  - wants to access `DataStorage`
- lib.rs of our runtime

  ```rust
  construct_runtime! {
     pub enum Runtime where
         Block = Block,
         NodeBlock = Block,
         UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
     {
         System: system::{Pallet},
         Provider: pallet_provider::{Pallet, Storage},
         Consumer: pallet_consumer::{Pallet}
     }
  }
  ```

### Create keys manually

Substrate's storage can be seen as a key-value-DB and the current storage types (`StorageValue`, `StorageMap` and `StorageDoubleMap`) just are convenience abstractions over this key-value logic. But in the end, they are always creating a deterministic key for accessing a specific value.

There is a really good deep dive into how the storage actually works from Shawn Tabrizi [here](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/substrate-storage-deep-dive/).

That being said one can access a pallet's storage elements by manually creating said keys.
All **pallet's** storage elements are created after the following logic:

- **StorageValue-Key:** `twox_128("PALLET_NAME")` + `twox_128("STORAGE_NAME")`
- **StorageMap-Key:** `twox_128("PALLET_NAME")` + `twox_128("STORAGE_NAME")` + `DEV_CHOOSEN_HASHER("KEY_1")`
- **StorageDoubleMap-Key:** `twox_128("PALLET_NAME")` + `twox_128("STORAGE_NAME")` + `DEV_CHOOSEN_HASHER("KEY_1")` + `DEV_CHOOSEN_HASHER("KEY_2")`

> ***NOTE:*** The `PALLET_NAME` is the name defined for the pallet in the `construct_runtime!()` macro.

For our above defined setup we could retrieve the `T::Data` from storage in the pallet_consumer as follows:

```rust
const PALLET_NAME: &'static str = "Provider";
const STORAGE_NAME: &'static str = "DataStorage";
type Index = u32;
type Data = u32;

fn get_storage_value(key: Index) -> Option<Data> {
    let pallet_hash = sp_io::hashing::twox_128(PALLET_NAME.as_bytes());
    let storage_hash = sp_io::hashing::twox_128(STORAGE_NAME.as_bytes());
    // Hashing the scale-encoded key
    let key_hashed = 
        frame_support::hash::Blake2_128Concat::hash(key.encode());

    let mut final_key = Vec::new();
    final_key.extend_from_slice(&pallet_hash);
    final_key.extend_from_slice(&storage_hash);
    final_key.extend_from_slice(&key_hashed);
    
    frame_support::storage::unhashed::get::<Data>(&final_key)
}
```

> ***NOTE:*** We have no way of checking whether our defined `Data` and `Index` types here, match with the `T::Data` and `T::Index` of the pallet_provider storage.

### Create `StorageMaps` manually

This solution uses the normal interface of the `StorageMaps` abstraction over storage. Meaning, one can use the created type just like any other normal storage element in substrate. BUT again, we manually define the names (pallet and storage) from which the final is key is generated.

Here, we would create a copy of the `pub type Data<T: Config>` in the pallet_consumer, but without binding it to the config. Hence, relying again on manually knowing the key type `T::Index` and the data type `T::Data`.

```rust
type Index = u32;
type Data = u32;

pub struct DataStorageCopyPrefix;
impl StorageInstance for DataStorageCopyPrefix {
    fn pallet_prefix() -> &'static str {
        "Provider"
    }

    const STORAGE_PREFIX: &'static str = "Data";
}

pub type DataStorageCopy<T> = frame_support::storage::types::StorageMap<
        DataStorageCopyPrefix,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        Index,
        Data,
    >;
```

> ***NOTE:*** We have no way of checking whether our defined `Data` and `Index` types here, match with the `T::Data` and `T::Index` of the pallet_provider storage.

### Abstraction via trait

This solution does not rely on knowledge of the underlying `StorageMap` in any way. Which, in my opinion is a bonus, as the pallet_provider is free to change the `StorageMap` without the need for the pallet_consumer to be changed.

- Define a trait that "abstracts" what the pallet_consumer wants

  ```rust
  trait DataProvider {
     type Key;
     type Data;

     fn query(key: Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Data>;
  ```
- Implement `DataProvider` for the `pallet_provider::Pallet`

  ```rust
  impl<T: Config> DataProvider for Pallet<T> {
     type Key = T::Index;
     type Data = T::Data;

     fn query(key: Self::Key) -> Option<Self::Data> {
        Data::<T>::get(&key)
     }
  }
  ```
- Create an associated type in the `pallet_consumer::Config`

  ```rust
  #[pallet::config]
  pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
      ...

      type Provider: DataProvider<Key = u32, Data = u32>;

      ...
  }
  ```

> ***NOTE:*** We are enforcing here, that the associated type that implements `DataProvider` is using the `Key` and `Index` we are expecting. Which gives us an error upon compile time if the used type for `Provider` in the runtime does not match this expectation.

### Summary

- The first two solutions are error prone, as changes in naming or types in the pallet_provder might be unnoticed by the pallet_consumer. This could result in unexpected errors or even UB if the decoding still succeeds.
- Solution 1 should be a last resort, but is generally useful to understand how keys for storage elements are generated. Furthermore, it allows querying storage via rpc methods for easily retrieving a whole map.
- Solution 2 could be a solution when a pallet has a private storage type and changes to that privacy or trait abstraction are out of reach (e.g. pallet is maintained by another team).
- Solution 3 should be favored in my opinion (if not tight-coupling). It allows to test the pallets independently of each other, it uses the compiler to ensure type-safety and is friendly to refactoring in the future.

Comment: Much cleaner! Thank you!

Comment: Would you consider option 2 to be unsafe in that it is quite possible to go around explicitly constructed guards to such storage?

Comment: Not sure. But I guess it fulfills everything to be regarded unsafe.

Comment: Thought about it a bit more. I guess reading is safe. Writing is unsafe. Omitting the problems that might result from unnoticed type changes, naming changes.

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging and help from mustermeiszer I was able to spot the problem.
In the problem was that I have the pallet defined as "LLM" and not "llm"(small cap) in the construct_runtime:

```rust
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = node_primitives::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        System: frame_system,
        Utility: pallet_utility,
        Babe: pallet_babe,
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp,
        // Authorship must be before session in order to note author in the correct session and era
        // for im-online and staking.
        Authorship: pallet_authorship,
        Indices: pallet_indices,
        Balances: pallet_balances,
        TransactionPayment: pallet_transaction_payment,
        AssetTxPayment: pallet_asset_tx_payment,
        ElectionProviderMultiPhase: pallet_election_provider_multi_phase,
        Staking: pallet_staking,
        Session: pallet_session,
        Democracy: pallet_democracy,
        Council: pallet_collective::<Instance1>,
        TechnicalCommittee: pallet_collective::<Instance2>,
        Elections: pallet_elections_phragmen,
        TechnicalMembership: pallet_membership::<Instance1>,
        Grandpa: pallet_grandpa,
        Treasury: pallet_treasury,
        Contracts: pallet_contracts,
        Sudo: pallet_sudo,
        ImOnline: pallet_im_online,
        AuthorityDiscovery: pallet_authority_discovery,
        Offences: pallet_offences,
        Historical: pallet_session_historical::{Pallet},
        RandomnessCollectiveFlip: pallet_randomness_collective_flip,
        Identity: pallet_identity,
        Society: pallet_society,
        Recovery: pallet_recovery,
        Vesting: pallet_vesting,
        Scheduler: pallet_scheduler,
        Preimage: pallet_preimage,
        Proxy: pallet_proxy,
        Multisig: pallet_multisig,
        Bounties: pallet_bounties,
        Tips: pallet_tips,
        Assets: pallet_assets,
        Mmr: pallet_mmr,
        Lottery: pallet_lottery,
        Gilt: pallet_gilt,
        Uniques: pallet_uniques,
        TransactionStorage: pallet_transaction_storage,
        BagsList: pallet_bags_list,
        StateTrieMigration: pallet_state_trie_migration,
        ChildBounties: pallet_child_bounties,
        Referenda: pallet_referenda,
        ConvictionVoting: pallet_conviction_voting,
        Whitelist: pallet_whitelist,
        LLM: pallet_llm, //{Pallet, Storage, Event<T>}, // LLM Pallet
    }
);
```

Based on centrifuge integration I created a mod for it:

```rust
pub mod llmmod {
    use super::*;
    use frame_support::{
        storage::types::{StorageMap, StorageValue, ValueQuery},
        traits::StorageInstance,
        Blake2_128Concat, Twox64Concat,
    };
    // ParaLifecyclesPrefix, based on centrifuge
    pub struct LLMPoliticsCopy;

    impl StorageInstance for LLMPoliticsCopy {
        fn pallet_prefix() -> &'static str {
            "LLM"
        }

        const STORAGE_PREFIX: &'static str = "LLMPolitics";
    }
    pub type LLMPolitics<T> = frame_support::storage::types::StorageMap<
        LLMPoliticsCopy,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        u128,
        frame_support::pallet_prelude::ValueQuery,
    >;
    //type AccountId = frame_system::Config::AccountId;

    pub fn check_pooled_llm<T: frame_system::Config>(sender: T::AccountId) -> bool {
        LLMPolitics::<T>::contains_key::<T::AccountId>(sender)
    }

    

    
}
```

Then in the other pallet I do a simple contains check to check for the account:

```rust
ensure!(!llmmod::check_pooled_llm::<T>(who.clone()), Error::<T>::NoPolLLM);
```